# Codeigniter 4: development environment works, production environment throws error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've used Codeigniter to build a simple web application. I've set up a development and production environment for localhost and the live server.

When I have the .env set to "development", everything works, even on the live server. As soon as I change .env to "production", my website throws an error:

> Argument 1 passed to CodeIgniter\Database\Database::load() must be of the type array, object given.

I can't figure out why this error wouldn't be thrown in development. So I think it's being thrown for the wrong reason?

.env

```
# Example Environment Configuration file
#
# This file can be used as a starting point for your own
# custom .env files, and contains most of the possible settings
# available in a default install.
#
# By default, all of the settings are commented out. If you want
# to override the setting, you must un-comment it by removing the '#'
# at the beginning of the line.
#--------------------------------------------------------------------

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# ENVIRONMENT
#--------------------------------------------------------------------

CI_ENVIRONMENT = production 

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# APP
#--------------------------------------------------------------------

# app.baseURL = ''
# app.forceGlobalSecureRequests = false

# app.sessionDriver = 'CodeIgniter\Session\Handlers\FileHandler'
# app.sessionCookieName = 'ci_session'
# app.sessionSavePath = NULL
# app.sessionMatchIP = false
# app.sessionTimeToUpdate = 300
# app.sessionRegenerateDestroy = false

# app.cookiePrefix = ''
# app.cookieDomain = ''
# app.cookiePath = '/'
# app.cookieSecure = false
# app.cookieHTTPOnly = false

# app.CSRFProtection  = false
# app.CSRFTokenName   = 'csrf_test_name'
# app.CSRFCookieName  = 'csrf_cookie_name'
# app.CSRFExpire      = 7200
# app.CSRFRegenerate  = true
# app.CSRFExcludeURIs = []

# app.CSPEnabled = false

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# DATABASE
#--------------------------------------------------------------------

# database.default.hostname = localhost
# database.default.database = ci4
# database.default.username = root
# database.default.password = root
# database.default.DBDriver = MySQLi

# database.tests.hostname = localhost
# database.tests.database = ci4
# database.tests.username = root
# database.tests.password = root
# database.tests.DBDriver = MySQLi

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# CONTENT SECURITY POLICY
#--------------------------------------------------------------------

# contentsecuritypolicy.reportOnly = false
# contentsecuritypolicy.defaultSrc = 'none'
# contentsecuritypolicy.scriptSrc = 'self'
# contentsecuritypolicy.styleSrc = 'self'
# contentsecuritypolicy.imageSrc = 'self'
# contentsecuritypolicy.base_uri = null
# contentsecuritypolicy.childSrc = null
# contentsecuritypolicy.connectSrc = 'self'
# contentsecuritypolicy.fontSrc = null
# contentsecuritypolicy.formAction = null
# contentsecuritypolicy.frameAncestors = null
# contentsecuritypolicy.mediaSrc = null
# contentsecuritypolicy.objectSrc = null
# contentsecuritypolicy.pluginTypes = null
# contentsecuritypolicy.reportURI = null
# contentsecuritypolicy.sandbox = false
# contentsecuritypolicy.upgradeInsecureRequests = false

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# HONEYPOT
#--------------------------------------------------------------------

#  honeypot.hidden = 'true'
#  honeypot.label = 'Fill This Field'
#  honeypot.name = 'honeypot'
#  honeypot.template = '<label>{label}</label><input type="text" name="{name}" value=""/>'
```

app/config/database

```
namespace Config;

/**
 * Database Configuration
 *
 * @package Config
 */

class Database extends \CodeIgniter\Database\Config
{
    /**
     * The directory that holds the Migrations
     * and Seeds directories.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $filesPath = APPPATH . 'Database/';

    /**
     * Lets you choose which connection group to
     * use if no other is specified.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $defaultGroup = 'development';

    /**
     * The default database connection.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $development = [
        'hostname' => 'localhost:8889',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => 'root',
        'database' => 'resources',
        'DBDriver' => 'MySQLi',
        'DBPrefix' => '',
        '     ' => TRUE,
        'DBDebug'  => TRUE,
        'cacheOn'  => FALSE,
        'cacheDir' => '',
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'DBCollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
        'swapPre'  => '',
        'encrypt'  => FALSE,
        'compress' => FALSE,
        'strictOn' => FALSE
    ];

    public $tests = [
        'hostname' => 'removed',
        'username' => 'removed',
        'password' => 'removed',
        'database' => 'removed',
        'DBDriver' => 'MySQLi',
        'DBPrefix' => '',
        'pConnect' => TRUE,
        'DBDebug' => TRUE,
        'cacheOn' => FALSE,
        'cacheDir' => '',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'DBcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
        'swap_pre' => '',
        'encrypt' => FALSE,
        'compress' => FALSE,
        'strictOn' => FALSE
    ];

    public $production = [
        'hostname' => 'removed',
        'username' => 'removed',
        'password' => 'removed',
        'database' => 'removed',
        'DBDriver' => 'MySQLi',
        'DBPrefix' => '',
        'pConnect' => TRUE,
        'DBDebug'  => TRUE,
        'cacheOn'  => FALSE,
        'cacheDir' => '',
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'DBCollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
        'swapPre'  => '',
        'encrypt'  => FALSE,
        'compress' => FALSE,
        'strictOn' => FALSE
    ];




    /**
     * This database connection is used when
     * running PHPUnit database tests.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    /*public $tests = [
        'DSN'      => '',
        'hostname' => '127.0.0.1',
        'username' => '',
        'password' => '',
        'database' => ':memory:',
        'DBDriver' => 'SQLite3',
        'DBPrefix' => 'db_',  // Needed to ensure we're working correctly with prefixes live. DO NOT REMOVE FOR CI DEVS
        'pConnect' => false,
        'DBDebug'  => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
        'cacheOn'  => false,
        'cacheDir' => '',
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'DBCollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
        'swapPre'  => '',
        'encrypt'  => false,
        'compress' => false,
        'strictOn' => false,
        'failover' => [],
        'port'     => 3306,
    ];*/

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        // Ensure that we always set the database group to 'tests' if
        // we are currently running an automated test suite, so that
        // we don't overwrite live data on accident.
        if (ENVIRONMENT === 'testing') {
            $this->defaultGroup = 'tests';

            // Under Travis-CI, we can set an ENV var named 'DB_GROUP'
            // so that we can test against multiple databases.
            if ($group = getenv('DB')) {
                if (is_file(TESTPATH . 'travis/Database.php')) {
                    require TESTPATH . 'travis/Database.php';

                    if (!empty($dbconfig) && array_key_exists($group, $dbconfig)) {
                        $this->tests = $dbconfig[$group];
                    }
                }
            }
        } elseif (ENVIRONMENT == 'development') {
            $this->defaultGroup = 'development';
        } else {
            $this->defaultGroup = ENVIRONMENT == 'production';
        }
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------

}
```

Why would my code work in development without error, but not in production?

I'm not even sure what other code to post as the CI_ENVIRONMENT is the only variable I'm changing.

Comment: The error message clearly says where the problem is: "CodeIgniter\Database\Database::load()".

Comment: That file is in the "System" directory of Codeigniter, where I haven't changed any code and it's supposed to be left alone.

Comment: As you didn't put any relevant code to the error you got, I suggest to check your DB connection parameters.

Comment: I've added my database config from app/config/database.php

Comment: Trace the relation of this function: CodeIgniter\Database\Database::load() to your application environment, i.e. that function depends on your application environment.
Search your codebase for that function.